# C++ std::string length() or size() not working on method args

Tags: c++, macos, stdstring

I have a method that that creates a MatLab array name from a file path and returns it as a std::string. the resulting string is passed into another method that writes the name to the file. When I try to get the length of the passed in string, it displays 0 when the length of the string is 12 or 13 chars.

My code:

```
bool MyClass::masterMethod(std::string fileURI){

 FILE* dataStream;
 // Assume dataStream is set up correctly

 // Get arrayName from File URI
 std::string arrayName = this->makeArrayNameFromPath( fileURI);

 //Write array name to file
 this->writeArrayName(arrayName , dataStream)



}


std::string MyClass::makeArrayNameFromPath(std::string filePathURI){


std::string tempString = filePathURI.substr(filePathURI.find_last_of('/')+1); 

std::string returnString = "";

long index = 0;

for(long i = 0; i < tempString.length(); i++){

    if((tempString[i] != ' ') && (tempString[i] != '.')){

        returnString[index++] = tempString[i];
    }
}

return returnString;

}



void MyClass::writeArrayName(std::string name , FILE *nameStream){

 // long testLength = name.length();
 // long testLength2 = name.size();
 // const char* testChar = nam.c_str();
 // long testCharLen = strlen(testChar);    

// The size of the name is the number of Chars * sizeof(int8_t)
int32_t sizeOfName = (int32_t)(name.length() * sizeof(int8_t));
int32_t nameType = miINT8;

fwrite(&nameType , sizeof(int32_t) , 1 , nameStream);
fwrite(&sizeOfName, sizeof(sizeOfName), 1, nameStream);
fwrite(&name , sizeof(name[0]), sizeOfName , nameStream);   

}
```

So I'm not sure why string::length is not working. If a create a std::string test = name,                          and print it , I can get the value of the string but can not get its length or size. 
If I use const char* testName = name.c_str(); long test = strlen(testName), I get a the 
correct value, but thought that wasn't necessary.

So any advice or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Your data is bad.  If `length` returns 0, then you have an empty string.  The library does not have a bug -- your code does.

Comment: Does your code really look like this?? Plz enhance the formatting, this makes my eyes bleed ...

Comment: Start passing your strings as const-reference since copying may be expensive.

Comment: @ipc while this is often true, see also http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Comment: @MarkB: Ouch!!! Another one fell into a misconception. The article clearly state that **if** you are going to copy internally you should take the argument by value. The **if** is the key point, if it is not going to be copied (as in this case), **don't** pass by value, as you will be paying the cost of an unnecessary copy.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas I hope I didn't make it sound like I was advocating always passing by value. I was just noting that you shouldn't always blindly pass by `const&`.

Comment: @ g-makulik Gimme a break. two simple methods to show the problem, and all you can comment on is a for loop not being indented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`returnString[index++] = tempString[i];` doesn't do what you think it does. It's not adding additional space or length to the string, only overwriting memory at a location that the string doesn't actually own. I think `returnString.append(1, tempString[i])` or similar should do it.

Comment: Oops your right! I never defined the size of the new string. That would explain it.

Answer (score 1):

You never give the string a size, just trying to assign positions that isn't there.

Try this instead to add characters to the return value

```
returnString += tempString[i];
```

Comment: Thank You for highlighting this. I probably made this same mistake in a few other places and need to go hunting to correct it.